# Why are some edges not visible/ covered by mesh?

Tags: modeling, interface, edges

[image]

So i am watching a blenderguru tutorial (Blender Beginner Modelling Tutorial - Part 4: Final Touches), but some edges are not visible. I am at a point where i seems to affect the workflow and i´m making mistakes.
I followed the tutorial accuratly, but i can´t explain why this doesn´t appear in it/ isn´t an issue.

Comment: Your edges are inside the subdivided mesh

Comment: Hm, so I obviously screwed up during the subsurf part. But isn´t there a way to make the black edges appear inthis view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling the "Ajust edit cage ..."  button in the subsurf modifier header

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also just found out that using the "button next to the face select" has the desired effect. I knew that button before, it´s pretty helpful!